# Need Help explaining this equation for the correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, random-variables, correlation, cauchy-integral-formula

As I am not a math geek so I have problem comprehending this equation:

[equation for the correlation coefficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0pc7.gif)

Its basically the formula used in the CORREL functon in Microsoft Excel and I am trying to manually compute it for the sake of learning.

So lets say I have data1 which contains 3,2,4,5,6 and data2 which has 9,7,12,15,17

So the average of data1 is 4 and the average of data2 is 12. (that I know) but what does the X and Y means?

Is the x the sum of data1 and y is the sum of data2?

And what does the greek alphabet  in the equation means?

Basically I just want someone who can explain it to me in plain english.

So I hope you dont mind explaining it to me like a kid :)

thanks in advance for your help.

source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CORREL-function-995dcef7-0c0a-4bed-a3fb-239d7b68ca92

Comment: The sequence that you call data1 can be looked at as outcomes $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$. Where do they come from? Well they are the outcomes taken by iid random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5$. The $X$ denotes a random variable equipped with their distribution. Likewise we have $Y$ linked with data2. Interpreted like that your correlation coefficient is an estimation of $\text{Cor}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little $x$ is a list of data. Little $y$ is another list of data.
In other words $x = (x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n)$. The large capital $\Sigma$ (sigma) signifies a [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). I think you understand that $\bar x,\bar y$ represent the averages of the respective data. Thus, for completeness, your formula should really read
\begin{align*}
\text{Corr}(X,Y) &= \frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}}{\displaystyle{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2\times\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar y)^2}}}\\
&=\frac{(x_1-\bar x)(y_1-\bar y)+\dotsb+(x_n-\bar x)(y_n-\bar y)}{\sqrt{[(x_1-\bar x)^2+\dotsb+(x_n-\bar x)^2][(y_1-\bar y)^2+\dotsb+(y_n-\bar y)^2}]}
\end{align*}

Finally, using your example (and better notation),
\begin{align*}
\text{Corr}(x,y)&= \frac{(3-4)(9-12)+\dotsb+(6-4)(17-12)}{\sqrt{[(3-4)^2+\dotsb+(6-4)^2][(9-12)^2+\dotsb+(17-12)^2]}}\\
&=\frac{26}{\sqrt{10\cdot68}}\\
&=0.9970545
\end{align*}

In plain English, the numerator is the sum of the product of each deviation from the mean with respect to the list $x$ and the list $y$. The denominator is the square root of the sum of the square of the deviations from list $x$ times the sum of the square of the deviations from list $y$. What does it all mean? We're trying to measure the linear relationship between the to data lists. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence).

Comment: that was quick! now I understand it. many thanks @probablyme

Comment: @anagnam Sure, no problem. A check mark would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes I was trying to do that but since I have less than 5 reputation so Im afraid it doesnt count as of yet. I mean it doesnt show publicly until i have 5 reps. thats what the error says.

Comment: I forget about that. No problem.

Comment: sorry i was confused either . now its checked. many thanks once again for your help @probablyme